# Swift not allowing me to set variable data

Tags: ios, swift, view, controller, segue

I am trying to create a simple contact list app as an avenue of learning Swift. Unfortunately no matter what I try I cannot have my contacts' details display into an editable text field on a different view controller to the tableview (which contains the main contacts).

Here is the block of code that should be effecting the text fields (i am unsure of what other code to supply)

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let object = objects[indexPath.row]
            let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
            print(object.firstName)
            controller.fiName?.text = object.firstName
            controller.laName?.text = object.lastName
            controller.miName?.text = object.middleName
            controller.aess?.text = object.address
            controller.phoNumber?.text = object.phoneNumber
            controller.yearBirth?.text = String(object.age)
            print(controller.fiName)
            controller.detailItem = object
            controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
            controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
        }
    }
```

The result of the first print line is as I expect it to be, which is the name of the contact, but the program crashes on the second print, with an 'EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION' / fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping and optional value.

Why can I not set the controller.fiName?.text? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you read my answer yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your `filName` is an `UILabel` or `UITextField` right?

If you check your code in `DetailViewController` you will notice this line:

```
@IBOutlet weak var filName: UITextField!
```

You see the `!` at the end of the line?

This means, that the variable (aka outlet) `filName` cannot be set at the initialization, but will be set at some point later.

Now, what you do is you init your class, and try to access that property that is not yet set at the initialization.

To get around this, create an object instance in `DetailViewController`, and set that instance to the selected object, and then set the label properties in the `viewDidLoad` function.

Something like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let object = objects[indexPath.row]
            let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
            controller.object = object
        }
}
```

And then in the `viewDidLoad` of `DetailViewController`:

```
override viewDidLoad() {
       fiName?.text = object.firstName
       laName?.text = object.lastName
       miName?.text = object.middleName
       aess?.text = object.address
       phoNumber?.text = object.phoneNumber
       yearBirth?.text = String(object.age)
       navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
       navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much for your response. When I implement the code like you've layed out , i still unexpectedly find nil while unwrapping an optional value. Additionally it seems like the object isn't being passed properly as there is no 'object.firstName' (but for some reason there is  an object.middleName ??)

Comment: I've figured it out, a simple and small mistake, I am eternally grateful for your help sir!

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the fiName label text too early, where the label hasn't been allocated yet. Instead pass through the object and then set the text in viewDidLoad of the next controller.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        let object = objects[indexPath.row]
        let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController

        //pass through object:
        controller.object = object

        print(object)
    }
}
```

And then in the next viewController viewDidLoad set the text:

```
override viewDidLoad() {
    //Now set the text value here:
    fiName?.text = object.firstName
}
```

Comment: Hi Joe! Thanks so much for your response. All of the answers gave me a much better understanding of what I was trying to do. Sorry I didn't reply to your answer sooner, I had half a response written and forgot about it :-) All the best

Comment: No problem @LiamS, it would be great if you could up vote/mark it as accepted for me. Hope I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Just object should be passed in `prepareForSegue`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let object = objects[indexPath.row]
                let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
                controller.detailItem = object
                controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
                controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
            }
        }
    }
```

And then outlets should be setup in `viewDidLoad`

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        fiName?.text = detailItem.firstName
        laName?.text = detailItem.lastName
        miName?.text = detailItem.middleName
        aess?.text = detailItem.address
        phoNumber?.text = detailItem.phoneNumber
        yearBirth?.text = String(detailItem.age)
    }
}
```